# What's the plastic piece on my camera mount?

Tags: tripod-socket

I recently bought a hand-held camera mount for my compact camera. The head-mount has a plastic tab on it similar to the one in the picture below. What is this tab for? Currently all it does is preventing me from opening the rotating screen, which is annoying.
[image]

Comment: I'VE ALWAYS WONDERED THAT and was too embarrassed to ask here! +1

Comment: If doing so doesn't impact how you use the camera, and it's in the way for you, I wouldn't be surprised if you can simply saw it off...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The pin adjacent to the mounting screw aligns with a matching hole on most all camcorders. This alignment scheme keeps the camcorder properly facing front. Still cameras have yet to adopt this scheme.

Comment: I would not use on still cameras because I want freedom, for example, when you use your tripod head at 90° to make a portrait framing.

Comment: If the pin is in the way of your rotating screen, you can try to turn your camera 90°, so that the pin is under the camera.